# How to get the Filtered data in the ListView.Builder : Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a JSON file where it has a bunch of Co-Ordinates. From that I'm calulating the nearest point/location from my current Location. I do am successfully calculating it and also getting the result by filtering within 2Km radius.

```
double pLat, pLng;
Position _currentPosition;
List<PinCodeModel> filteredPinCodes = List();

Future loadPinCode() async {
    _currentPosition = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    String jsonString = await loadPinCodeData();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);

    setState(() {
      for (Map pincode in jsonResponse){
        PinCodeModel pinCodeModel = PinCodeModel.fromJson(pincode);

        pLat = double.parse(pinCodeModel.latitude.toString());
        pLng = double.parse(pinCodeModel.longitude.toString());
        OfficeName = pinCodeModel.officeName.toString();
        pinCode = pinCodeModel.pincode.toString();
        contactNumber = pinCodeModel.contactNumber.toString();

        final double distance = Geolocator.distanceBetween(pLat, pLng, _currentPosition.latitude, _currentPosition.longitude);
        if(distance<2000){
          print(OfficeName + pinCode + contactNumber + distance.toString());
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Yes I'm getting the values printed successfully, but I just need to know how i can display it in ListView.Builder or any someother way perhaps.

Upon looking at the comments I made some changes as

```
Future loadPinCode() async {
    _currentPosition = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    String jsonString = await loadPinCodeData();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);

    setState(() {
      for (Map pincode in jsonResponse){
        PinCodeModel pinCodeModel = PinCodeModel.fromJson(pincode);
        List pinCodeList = jsonResponse.map((e) => PinCodeModel.fromJson(pincode)).where((element){
          pLat = double.parse(pinCodeModel.latitude.toString());
          pLng = double.parse(pinCodeModel.longitude.toString());
          postOfficeName = pinCodeModel.officeName.toString();
          pinCode = pinCodeModel.pincode.toString();
          contactNumber = pinCodeModel.contactNumber.toString();
          final double distance = Geolocator.distanceBetween(pLat, pLng, _currentPosition.latitude, _currentPosition.longitude);
          return distance < 2000;
        }).toList();
      }
    });
  }
```

And this is how I'm trying to show in the UI

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              return ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(pinCodeList[index].pincode),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: pinCodeList.length,
              );
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          }, future: loadPinCode(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: make your list render from a array and then in set state overwrite the array

Comment: try with stream builder

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a list with your filtered data and use it inside ListView.builder().

Here is the code to get filtered data:

```
List<PinCodeModel> yourList jsonResponse.map((e) => PinCodeModel.fromJson(pincode)).where((element) {
      pLat = double.parse(pinCodeModel.latitude.toString());
      pLng = double.parse(pinCodeModel.longitude.toString());

      OfficeName = pinCodeModel.officeName.toString();
      pinCode = pinCodeModel.pincode.toString();
      contactNumber = pinCodeModel.contactNumber.toString();

      final double distance = Geolocator.distanceBetween(pLat, pLng, _currentPosition.latitude, _currentPosition.longitude);
      return distance < 2000;
    }).toList();
```

And then just:

```
ListView.build(itemCount: yourList.length(), itemBuilder (context, index) { return your item widget here using yourList[index]; })
```

Comment: I see you updated your question with the new code. It's not all, but from what I can see inside setState() method you create a new list, which is a local variable and inside build() method for ListView.builder you're using another list variable, probably class level. You're just using the wrong list